# Keplr keeps overriding fees set from the frontend

Tags: archway-network

I realize that Keplr keeps overriding the fees that I set in my frontend dapp and therefore it's not considering the contract premium set for my contract. How can I force Keplr to use the fees set in the frontend?

```
const broadcastResult = await signingClient.signAndBroadcast(
    accounts[0].address,
    [msgAny],
    "auto",
    memo,
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Keplr overrides the transaction fee on the signing page, regardless of whether the frontend has defined its own fees which is the case with **arch3.js**. This has led to significantly higher transaction fees in some instances. To address this problem, we recommend that dapp frontends make use of the Interactive Options (https://docs.keplr.app/api/#interaction-options) feature within Keplr. This feature will give priority to the frontend-suggested fee instead of overriding it.

```
window.keplr.defaultOptions = {
    sign: {
        preferNoSetFee: true,
    }
}
```